# Why is unzipping .csvs to DataFrames sluggish?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, zip, python-polars

I'm tackling a challenge where I need to create a list of DataFrames from zipped CSVs. The master zip file exceeds 1GB and contains multiple CSVs. My objective is to extract specific CSVs (whose filenames matches a pattern) from the master file and process them accordingly. Currently, I'm using Polars and Pandas.

Surprisingly :

- using Polars, the process takes 20 seconds today (compared to 10 seconds yesterday)
- while with Pandas, it now requires 45 seconds (compared to 30 seconds yesterday).

> **PS** : *Each matched CSV file contains 90 columns and on average, is around
> 100MB.*

Here is my code :

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
import polars as pl
import re

dtypes_to_use = {
    'Date': pl.Date,
    'Item': pl.Utf8,
    'Value': pl.UInt16,
    'Name': pl.Utf8,
    'Code': pl.Utf8,
}

pattern = re.compile(r'.+_(\w+)_SE_(\d+)_.+')

data = []
with ZipFile("data/master.zip") as zip_file:
    for file_name in zip_file.namelist():
        if m := pattern.match(file_name):
            data.append(
                pl.read_csv(
                    zip_file.open(file_name),
                    separator=';',
                    dtypes=dtypes_to_use,
                    columns=dtypes_to_use.values(),
                ).with_columns(
                    pl.lit(m.group(1)).alias('SectionName'),
                    pl.lit(m.group(2)).alias('SectionId'),
                )
            )
```

I'm so confused! I can't understand why the process takes this much.

Any help or advice would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Because Disk IO is slow. And (de)compression takes its time. Why would you expect this to be faster? What kind of disk do you have, what speed?

Comment: Hi. 1) Because being this slow, is conterintuitive for me. 2)- I have this one SK Hynix 256 GB BC511 NVMe.

Comment: You can use `pl.scan_csv()` and `pl.collect_all()` to load them in parallel.

Comment: Hi @jqurious, I will be more than happy if you can show me how to proceed because I'm not familiar with these two functions.

Comment: Maybe you can try `multiprocessing` to load each CSV in separate process?

Comment: I should have tested first. It seems `.scan_csv` doesn't currently support reading directly from `zipfile.open()`

Comment: jqurious, no problem. Andrej Kesely, can you please show me how to multiprocess ?